# Вопрос по рекурсии

Tags: javascript

Задачка из книги "Выразительный JavaScript"

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
        find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(13));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)
```

Не могу понять как в history попадает эта строка (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) ?

Comment: чтобы понять, нужно идти по шагам

Comment: Да но не могу врубиться вот стек:  find('6', '1+5') => find('11', + (1+5)+5) но откуда в друг такой вариант прилетает в history (1*3)+5+5

Comment: из второй ветки _find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");_

Comment: )) почему именно так  (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)  а не (3, (1*3)) ==> (9, (1*3)*3) вот где я застрял: (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)  откуда там сложение и следующие данные (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)

Comment: find(9, "(1*3)*3") вызовет find(27, ...) и find(14, ...), а они обе вернут null

Answer (score 5):

Короче, я тут немного рехнулся, и написал то, что делает эта программа пошагово, может кому-нибудь пригодится
/* Разбор прохода программы, когда значение равно 24:

```
1. Сначала инициализируется функция find внутри функции findSolution
2. Начинается выполнение логических блоков со строки return find(1, "1"), когда запускается функция find c аргументами 1 и "1"
3. Вошли в функцию find и создали для её this две переменные start = 1 и historyFind = "1"
4. Первое логическое условие отрабатывает на false, так как 1 не равен 24, пропускаем тело логики
5. Второе условие дает тоже false, так как 1 не больше 24 - пропускаем
6. Логическое условие else без if позволяет запустить логическое тело
    ВНИМАНИЕ: ПЕРВЫЙ СТЕК: с этого момента начинается логическая развилка, потому что чтобы выполнить код с оператором || интерпретатор должен вычислить выражение до оператора || и вернуть либо true либо false, и все изменения переменных start и historyFind получают неопределённый статус, то ли временных (потому что если выражение вернет в итоге false то все изменения забудутся) то ли постоянных (если в итоге даст true). Оригинальные значения переменных до этого момента будут храниться в стеке и будут равны 1 и "1" и будут доступны если итоговое вычисление выражения || даст true. Это первый стек, стек1, в котором start=1, historyFind="1"
    7. Запускается функция find, в которую передаются аргументы start = 1+5 и historyFind = "(1 + 5)"
    8. Первое логическое условие отрабатывает как false, так как 6 не равен 24
    9. Второе логическое условие отрабатывает как false, так как 6 не больше 24
    10. Третий логический блок запускается, так как ELSE без IF
        ВНИМАНИЕ: ВТОРОЙ СТЕК: так как опять мы встретились со второй развилкой, то интерпретор создает второй стек, в который занесет состояние переменных, чтобы вернуть их если эта развилка итогом вернет false. Это второй стек, стек2, start=6 (так как мы шли по той ветке, которая выполняет сложение), historyFind = "(1+5)"
        11. Запускается функция find, в которую передаются аргументы start = 11, historyFind = "((1+5)+ 5)"
        12. Первое логическое условие дает false, так как 11 не равен 24
        13. Второе логическое условие дает false, так как 11 не больше 24
        14. Третье логическое условие дает TRUE, так как else без if
            ВНИМАНИЕ: ТРЕТИЙ СТЕК: мы опять встретились с развилкой (мы уйдем с этих развилок либо когда start станет равным target, либо когда обе развилки, которые на первом стеке, потому что, по сути мы пока что выполняем получение итога первой части первой развилки, дадут false). Итак стек3: start = 11, historyFind = "((1+5)+5)"
            15. Запускается функция find в которую передаются аргументы start = 16 и historyFind = "(((1+5)+5)+5)"
            16. Первое логическое условие дает false, так как 16 не равен 24
            17. Второе логическое условие дает false, так как 16 не больше 24
            18. Третье логическое условие даёт true, так как else без if
                ВНИМАНИЕ: ЧЕТВЕРТЫЙ СТЕК: мы опять встретились с развилкой (все еще по сути выполняя первую развилку), уходим на тропу сложения, но в стек4 заносим значения переменных start = 16 и historyFind = "(((1+5)+5)+5)" которые станут постоянными если итогом выполнения придет true
                19. Запускается функция find, в которую передаются аргументы start = 21 и historyFind = "((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)"
                20. Первое логическое условие false, так как 21 не равен 24
                21. Второе логическое условие false, так как 21 не больше 24
                22. Третье логическое условие true, так как else без if это true
                    ВНИМАНИЕ: ПЯТЫЙ СТЕК: мы опять встретились с развилкой выполняя рекурсию по первой развилке, заносит в стек5 start = 21 и historyFind = "(((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)"
                    23. Запускается функция find с аргументами start = 26 и historyFind = "(((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)+5)"
                    24. Первое условие даёт false, так как 26 не равен 24
                    25. Второе условие ВНЕЗАПНО дает true, и тело этого логического блока дало в ответ NULL, что в JavaScript равносильно false для логического условия, поэтому возвращаеся к предыдущей развилке, забыв про все изменения переменных в выполнении после пятого стека
                    26. Опять принимаем значение переменных start = 21 и historyFind = "(((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)" и запускаем второй вариант развилки
                    27. Запускается вторая развилка после пятого стека, в которой запускается функция find c аргументами start * 3 и historyFind = "(((((1+5)+5)+5)+5)*3)"
                    28. Первое условие даёт false, так как 21*3 не равен 24
                    29. Второе условие даёт опять ВНЕЗАПНО true, но оно и понятно, ведь 63 больше 24 и тело этого логического блока запускается и дает NULL в ответку (RETURN)
                    30. Тут мы понимаем что оба условия внезапно дали FALSE и мы возвращаемся к предыдущему стеку, ведь МЫ ДО СИХ ПОР ВЫПОЛНЯЕМ ПЕРВУЮ РАЗВИЛКУ ПО СУТИ
                31. Забываем про все изменения в пятом стеке, ведь мы вернулись на четвертый уровень вложенности, а там свой стек, который до сих пор хранит в себе значения переменных равными start = 16 и historyFind = "(((1+5)+5)+5)" и для КОТОРОГО ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ ЛОГИЧЕСКОЙ РАЗВИЛКИ В СТОРОНУ TRUE УЖЕ ДАЛО FALSE
                32. Итак, выполнение развилки 4 стека дало false после прохода по сложению, и поэтому развилка начинает второй вариант
                33. Запускается find, куда будут переданы аргументы start=16*3 и historyFind = "(((1+5)+5)+5)*3"
                34. Проверяется первое логического условие: false, так как 48 не равен 24
                35. Проверяется второе логическое условие: ВНЕЗАПНО true, ибо 48 > 24 и выполняется тело второго логического блока, которое возвращает NULL
                36. Обе развилки стека4 дали false и программа ПРОДОЛЖАЕТ ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ ПЕРВОЙ РАЗВИЛКИ возвращаясь к предыдущему стеку, стеку3, забыв про все изменения внутри процедур после 4 стека
            37. Мы вернулись на третий уровень стека, переопределяем переменные теми значениями переменных, которые хранятся в стеке: стек3: start = 11, historyFind = "((1+5)+5)"
            38. Как вы наверное понимаете, выполнение после стека3 начиналось со сложения и вернуло false, но мы не выполняли правое выражение после || которое умножает, поэтому мы опять рекурсивно запускаем find
            39. Запускаем find в который передаем значение переменных: start = 11*3, historyFind = "(((1+5)+5)*3)"
            40. Первое логическое условие дало false, так как 33 не равен 24
            41. Второе логическое условие, ни разу ни внезапно, но даёт true, ибо 33 > 24, тело которого возвращает NULL, то-есть FALSE в JavaScript
            42. Приходит понимание того, обе развилки третьего уровня стека дали false и потому мы забываем про все изменения переменных и трансгрессируем на второй уровень стека
        43. На втором уровне стека мы переопределяем переменные: start=6*3 , historyFind = "((1+5)*3)"
        44. Запускаем рекурсивно функцию find, в которую передаём аргументы start = 18 и historyFind = "((1+5)*3)"
        45. Первый логический блок дает false, так как 18 не равно 24
        46. Второй логический блок даёт false, так как 18 не больше 24
        47. Третий логический блок даёт true, так как else всегда даёт true и мы создав стек6, в который занесём переменные start и historyFind со значениями 18 и ((1+5)*3) соответственно
            48. ВНИМАНИЕ: ШЕСТОЙ СТЕК: который хранит в себе значения переменных 18 и ((1+5)*3) и тут еще ни одной развилки не выполнялось, поэтому уходит на первую развилку шестого стека, на сложение: ВНИМАНИЕ, а мы все еще выполняем ПЕРВУЮ РАЗВИЛКУ ПЕРВОГО СТЕКА, по сути
            49. Запускаем функцию find, в которую передаём значения переменных start = 18+5 и history = (((1+5)*3)+5)
            50. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 23 не равен 24
            51. Второе логическое условие даёт false, так как 23 не больше 24
            52. Третье логическое условие дает true, так как else и создается стек7, куда заносятся значения переменных start = 23 и historyFind = (((1+5)*3)+5)
                ВНИМАНИЕ: СОЗДАН СЕДЬМОЙ СТЕК: стек7, куда помещаются значения переменных start = 23 и historyFind = (((1+5)*3)+5)
                53. Запускается рекурсив find, в которую передаём значения переменных start = 23+5 и historyFind = ((((1+5)*3)+5)+5)
                54. Первое логическое условие даёт false, ибо 28 не равен 24
                55. Второе логическое условие даёт true, так как 28 > 24 и возвращается null
                56. Переменные сбросились и стали равными стеку start = 23 и historyFind = (((1+5)*3)+5)
                57. Первая развилка вычислила первое выражение до || и дала false, поэтому начинает вычислятся вторая развилка седьмого стека
                58. Начинается вторая развилка седьмого стека, которая запускает рекурсивно функцию find, передав ей аргументы start = 23*3 и historyFind = ((((1+5)*3)+5)*3)
                59. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 69 не равен 24
                60. Второе логическое условие даёт true, так как 69 больше 24 и возвращается null
                61. Стек7 в итоге становится FALSE, так как обе его развилки вернули FALSE и отдаёт управление на верхний уровень, на стек6
            62. Сбрасываем значение переменных до уровня стека и инициализируем их значениями шестого уровня стека start = 18 и historyFind = "((1+5)*3)"
            63. По факту первую развилку стека6 мы уже выполнили и она вернула false, поэтому мы запускаем вторую развилку шестого стека
            64. Запускаем функцию find и передаём ей аргументы start = 18*3, historyFind = "(((1+5)*3)*3)"
            65. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 54 не равен 24
            66. Второе логическое условие даёт true, так как 54 больше 54 и возвращает NULL, то-есть false
            67. Итогово шестой стек на обоих развилках получил FALSE, стал равным FALSE, и передал управление на верхний уровень, ведь мы ещё до сих пор вычисляем ПЕРВУЮ РАЗВИЛКУ ПЕРВОГО СТЕКА
        68. ВТОРОЙ СТЕК в итоге всех предыдущих операций на обоих развилках получил FALSE и передает управление в Стек1, в ПЕРВЫЙ СТЕК
    69. ИТАК: ВНИМАНИЕ: ВНЕЗАПНО ПЕРВАЯ РАЗВИЛКА НАКОНЕЦ ТО ВЫПОЛНИЛАСЬ И ОКАЗАЛОСЬ ЧТО ОНА FALSE
    70. ПЕРВЫЙ СТЕК ПЕРЕОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ И start = 1, historyFind = "1"
    71. Так как первая развилка первого стека дала false, то начинаем вторую развилку первого стека
    72. Запускаем функцию find и передаём ей аргументы start = 1*3 и historyFind = "(1*3)"
    Лирическое отступление: я как представлю сколько ещё писать, то так и хочется завыть
    73. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 3 не равен 24
    74. Второе логическое условие даёт false, так как 3 не больше 24
    75. Третье логическое условие даёт true, так как else даёт true
        ВНИМАНИЕ: СОЗДАН ВОСЬМОЙ СТЕК, сюда будет занесено значение переменных start = 3 и historyFind = "(1*3)"
        76. Запускается первая развилка восьмого стека
        77. Запускает функция find, в которую передаются аргументы 3+5 и "((1*3)+5)"
        78. Проверяется первое логическое условие и оно даёт false, так как 8 не равен 24
        79. Второе логическое условие даёт false, так как 8 не больше 24
        80. Третье логическое условие даёт true, так как else даёт true
            ВНИМАНИЕ: СОЗДАН ДЕВЯТЫЙ СТЕК, в который помещается значение переменных 8 и "((1*3)+5)"
            81. Запускается рекурсив find, в который передаются аргументы 8+5 и "(((1*3)+5)+5)"
            82. Проверяется первое условие и оно даёт false, так как 13 не равен 24
            83. Проверяется второе логическое условие и оно даёт false, так как 13 не больше 24
            84. Третье логическое условие даёт true, потому что ... ну вы поняли, да?
                ВНИМАНИЕ: создан десятый стек, стек10, в который будет помещено значение переменных start = 13 и historyFind = "(((1*3)+5)+5)"
                85. Запускается первая развилка десятого стека
                86. Функция find получает аргументы 13+5 и ((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)
                87. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 18 не равен 24
                88. Второе логическое условие даёт false, так как 18 не больше 24
                89. Третье логическое условие даёт как обычно true, ибо else даёт вегда true
                    ВНИМАНИЕ: создан одиннадцатый стек, стек11, в который помещаются значения переменных start = 18 и historyFind = ((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)
                    90. Запускается первая развилка одиннадцатого стека, который запускает рекурсию find, передавая в неё аргументы 18+5 и (((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)
                    91. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 23 не равен 24
                    92. Второе логическое условие даёт false, так как 23 не больше 24
                    93. Третье логическое даёт true
                        ВНИМАНИЕ: СОЗДАН ДВЕНАДЦАТЫЙ СТЕК, в который будет помещены значения переменных = 23 и (((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)
                        94. Запускается первая развилка двенадцатого стека, стека12, в которой запускается функция find с аргументами 23+5 и ((((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)+5)
                        95. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 28 не равен 24
                        96. Второе логическое условие даёт TRUE, внезапно, выполняется тело этого логического блока, которое возвращает NULL
                        97. Так как на первой развилке вернулся FALSE, то запускается вторая развилка двенадцатого стека
                        98. В которой запускается рекурсивная функция find с аргументами 23*3 и ((((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)+5)*3)
                        99. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 69 не равен 24
                        100.Второе логическое условие даёт true, ибо 69 > 24, и тело этого блока возвращает NULL
                        101.Обе развилки вернули FALSE, поэтому возвращаемся на уровень выше и переопределяем значения переменных из верхнего стека
                    102. Так как первая развилка итогом дала FALSE, то запускается вторая развилка, с переменными из этого стека11
                    103. Запускается функция find, которая получает переменные start = 18*3 и historyFind = (((((1*3)+5)+5)+5)*3)
                    104. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 54 не равен 24
                    105. Второе логическое условие даёт true, так как 54 больше 24 и запускается тело второго логического блока, которое возвращает NULL
                    106. Так как обе развилки стека11 вернули FALSE, то возвращаемся на десятый уровень и переопределяем переменные значениями из стека10
                107. Первая развилка итогом дала FALSE, потому запускаем вторую развилку десятого стека
                108. Запускаем функцию find, в которую передаём аргументы start = 13*3 и historyFind = "((((1*3)+5)+5)*3)"
                109. Первое логическое условие даёт false, так как 39 не равен 24
                110. Второе логическое условие даёт true, так как 39 больше 24, запускается тело второго логического блока, которое возвращает NULL
                111. Таким образом обе развилки стека10 вернули false, и поэтому возвращаемся на уровень выше и переопределяем переменные
            112. Первая развилка девятого стека дала false, вследствии этого запускается вторая развилка девятого стека
            113. Вызывается функция find, которой аргументами передаются 8*3 и "(((1*3)+5)*3"
            114. ВНЕЗАПНО, СУЧКА: ПЕРВОЕ ЛОГИЧЕСКОЕ УСЛОВИЕ ДАЁТ ДОЛГОЖДАННЫЙ TRUE и выполняется тело первого логического блока, который возвращает результат вызова функции find, то-есть переменную historyFind, которую из непостоянно переменчивой делает наконец-то постоянной и отдаёт в функцию findSolution
115. Функция findSolution получает результат работы функции find и передаёт этот результат тому, кто вызывал функцию findSolution, то-есть в глобальную область видимости, функции console.log(), которая выводит на экран результат работы функции findSolution, то-есть строковую переменную historyFind равную "(((1*3)+5)*3"
```

Comment: @rjhdby вы убили правильную нумерацию своей правкой)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ммм, действительно. Но так хотя бы какая то нумерация появилась, а не поток сознания из /dev/astral :) поправьте, если сдюжите. Я не рискну.

Comment: @rjhdby на самом деле там уже был список, просто автор не знал что на выходе он склеется...... надо бы просто применить Ctrl + K и оставить так как код, имхо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, оптимальный вариант. Лучше так, чем в один уровень.

Answer (score 1):

Работа рекурсии по задачке выше

[image: work recursion]

Answer (score 0):

**history** - это параметр с которым вызывается функция **find**

Строка

> return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") || find(start * 3, "("
>   + history + " * 3)");

значит, что если **find** с первым параметром **start + 5** вернет **null**, то она вызовется с первым параметром **start * 3** (а вторым параметром передается история + то с каким параметром она вызвана сейчас)

Судя по истории функция **find** вызывалась (и вернула не null) три раза. Первый раз с параметром **start * 3**, второй и третий с **start + 5**

P.S.: если вам что то не понятно на каком то шаге, то берите дебаггер и по строчкам смотрите что происходит.

Comment: спс, но все таки не понятка в том что history до попадания с условием null возвратила строку ((1 + 5) + 5) то почему вдруг число 1 уже не участвует? и получился такой результат (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5) а не   ((1+ 5) + 5) * 3)

Comment: что то я запутался попробую в debugger глянуть

Comment: я тоже не понял что вы написали)

Comment: спс в debugger все разъяснилось)) прикольная задача